# Is there a way to statically map MAC addresses to IP addresses for machines in MAAS?

Tags: juju, maas, dhcp, openstack

I have few (11) servers in MAAS that will be used for OpenStack deployment. I want to give specific IP addresses to specific nodes in the MAAS. Is there a way to map the MAC address to IP address so that servers don't get random IP from the DHCP pool. I am using the MAAS server as the DHCP server.

Comment: You can assign specific IPs to MAC address in the DHCP server.

Answer (score 1):

Work is currently under way to enable you to bind an IP address to a machine so that it is always used whenever that machine is brought up.

Similarly, it will be possible to declare additional (unmanaged) machines (MAC and IP) so that you can have DNS and DHCP for them provided by MAAS rather than having them statically assigned and unrecorded in MAAS.